# Remove a file on JPA orphan-delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have an entity linked with my filesystem like this :

```
@Entity
public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private Long documentId;
    private String fileName;
    private String filePath;
    //Then a lot of other fields, getters and setters
}
```

If I delete a document from my database (with orphan-delete for example), I want to remove the corresponding file in an Async method.

Any suggestion ? Is there a way to intercept JPA delete action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up event lifecycle for entities, specifically preRemove.

With annotation configuration is as easy as doing

```
@PreRemove
public void deleteFile(){
  //your async logic
}
```

Edit : you could also create a separated service like that :

```
@Service
public class FilerService {
    @PostRemove 
    @Async
    void deleteFile(MyDocument document) {
        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(document.getFilePath()));
    }
}
```

And bind it with `@EntityListeners`

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(FilerService.class)
public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private Long documentId;
    private String fileName;
    private String filePath;
    //Then a lot of other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's I was looking for. I added this interceptor in another Service : http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event#Listeners_and_External_Callback_Methods_